# how can we list NFT in opensea without minting?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft

I have a minting contract. If I mint the NFTs it will displayed on the open sea. But what I want that is to display NFTs on opensea without minting.and when i buy the Nft then it will call my NFT contract .
OpenSea, allowing you to create your own NFTs completely for free, without paying any gas fee but for this we initialize opensea account and then manually add the nfts.i have 10000 nft and i want to list down to opensea without minting through any api or some other approach .and when buyer come to buy it will then mint and transfer (but it will also call my contract mint function )

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about lazy minting. OpenSea and Rarible have this method for free listing tokens. But you can only lazyMint an NFT in their contracts. Because it is a special method. When users come to their website and list their token, their databases save all the information about the listed NFT. When somebody comes to buy it, the buyer mint and gets it. In their openseCollection contract.

For more info you can google it `opensea lazy mint` or `rarible lazy mint`.